# How to use wifi direct on windows using intel my wifi dashboard

Tags: windows, wireless-networking

I think I have it installed correctly with an intel advanced-n 6200 card (windows 7), I can turn on wifi-direct and see "ralink client" (another pc on windows 8.1 with an rt5572 chipset usb adapter) and my samsung phone but all I can do on both is just renaming or blocking them.

Turning on the hotspot function seems to add some more client and makes a new access point appear on my phone as "direct-qu-PC-NAME" but not on my other computer (which could be an issue on its own).

Am I doing something wrong, or is wifi-direct simply that, a device turning into an Access Point while being itself a client?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, I got a new phone, which has a working WiFi Direc interface. I could initiate a connection with it to the PC easely. Gotta find out what's wrong on my ralink client now -_-

Comment: how did you do this?